# How do I send credentials(accessToken) with axios requests?

Tags: reactjs, axios

When users login, I send an axios post request to the login endpoint with its required credentials(accessToken). everything works fine. After a successful login, they are redirected to the homepage where I make i get request. The request doesn't send the credentials whixh of course would return an unauthenticated error. Even when I specify this in the axios get request it still woudn't work.

```
withCredentials: true
```

on postman and Insomnia, the token is sent successfully and the correct data is gotten, but It just will not work on the web. What could be wrong?

ths is the useFetch code

```
    try {
        await axios({
        url: `https://crayonnne-jotter-server.herokuapp.com/api${url}`,
        method: "get",
        withCredentials: true,
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res) 
    });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the `accessToken` through the headers.

```js
axios({
  ... // other stuff
  headers: {
       Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  },
})
```